# running toad query - seems to work but does not update the table

Tags: sql, toad

I am using the script below to populate 2 separate columns in a table: `SEARCH_DESC` and `SEARCH_TAG`. I'm running it and it seems to work with no errors, but its not updating. There are around 190 rows to update with this data - is it just the amount of text and its slow or is the script wrong? Have pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> but the only row that updates is the last one ie. SERV_ID = 47?

```
UPDATE some_table
SET SEARCH_DESC = 'This is the description text.',
  SEARCH_TAG = 'word, word2, word3, word4'
WHERE SERV_ID = 38;

UPDATE some_table
SET SEARCH_DESC = 'This is the description text.',
  SEARCH_TAG = 'word, word2, word3, word4'
WHERE SERV_ID = 45;

UPDATE some_table
SET SEARCH_DESC = 'This is the description text.',
  SEARCH_TAG = 'word, word2, word3, word4'
WHERE SERV_ID = 47;
```

Comment: Make sure you highlight the three queries before pressing F5.

Comment: My suspection: select count(*) from table where serv_id in (38,45,47); gives 190??? Also there is an option to EXECUTE AS SCRIPT (F5) in toad. This will run all three and post the results, if selected as block.

Comment: Sorry this is just 3 of the 190 serv_ids. I tried to highlight the whole thing and run as script but it took forever and I've ended up cancelling it. Hmm, will